# "For every day" vs. "with every day"

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions

Consider

> (…) and they were getting stronger **with/for** every day

What's the difference/the correct one to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (…) and they were getting stronger *with* every day

*With* is correct here because it indicates the "getting stronger" and the "every day" are occurring simultaneously, or *with* each other. *For* is incorrect here because it would indicate that whoever/whatever is getting stronger is doing for the purpose of "every day," which is nonsensical.

However, the preposition could be dropped altogether with no loss of meaning:

> (…) and they were getting stronger every day

Comment: but you could validly say "**for every day at the health farm, I lost 3 ounces**"

Answer (score 1):

The correct word here is *with*. I would not use *every* with it, however, but would phrase it like this:

> They were getting stronger with each passing day.

If use of "every day" is important to you, you could phrase it this way, without any preposition:

> They were getting stronger every day.

Comment: *with each passing day* — exactly what I was thinking! Nice!